# progressView in today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

I have a progress view in a today extension that shows progress of a download and it works, but just for the first time and the next time you open the extension although download is being performed but progressView is not being updated .

```
@interface TodayViewController () <NCWidgetProviding>{
    NSURLSession * session;
    NSString * clipboard;
    NSString * jsonTitle;
}


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView;

@end

- (NSURLSession *) configureDownloadSession {
    if (!session) {
        NSURLSessionConfiguration * sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier: @"bgSessionConfiguration"];
        sessionConfiguration.sharedContainerIdentifier = @"group.myapp";
        sessionConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    }
    return session;
}
session = [self configureDownloadSession];
            NSURLSessionDownloadTask * downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[json objectForKey:@"formats"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"link"]]];
            jsonTitle=[[[json objectForKey:@"formats"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"title"];
            [downloadTask resume];

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    float progress = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%f",progress);
        self.progressView.progress=progress;
        [mySharedDefaults synchronize];
    });
}
```

Comment: Show us codes before we can help. No clue what you are talking about.

Comment: @Raptor there you go...

Comment: I've use a chronometer to update the progress bar every 1 second during a download: https://github.com/vitor251093/NSDownload It was made for macOS, but I guess you can easily modify it to work in iOS. It also has a progress subtitle, with amount downloaded, amount needed and speed ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try